# ExtJS: the magic of hidden columns

Tags: css, extjs, hidden

I wonder how ExtJS makes columns hidden without any visible CSS changes![image: hidden column ant not hidden]

The problem that I had - I can't set the CSS rule to hide children icon in that hidden column. F.e. if the hidden td had class 'hidden', I can use something like that:

```
td.hidden img {display:none;}
```

But in this case I can do it only in renderer with manipulating grid.columns[col].isHidden().

```
renderer: function(value,td,record,row,col,store,view) {
    return grid.columns[col].isHidden() ? '' : someFunctionToRenderColumn();
},
```

It's ok, but then if I show hidden column it will not refresh grid and shows empty column. Of course I can add one more event for show/hide that column, but it is so difficult! Has it any simple way?

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question? You're expected to mark it as accepted if it does... FYI the rendering process has changed in Ext4.2.1. In this version, hidden column are not rendered at all (i.e. no HTML elements), so that should fix your issue whatever its cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives them a width of 0px:

```
<colgroup>
    <col class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1023" style="width: 0px;">
</colgroup>
```

... and that should hide your `img` too. Except if you've given them an absolute positionning or something. You should try to position your `img` using `float`, `margin` and `padding`. Or you will have to toggle the `'hidden'` class yourself using the `hide` and `show` event of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide columns by targeting the corresponding `col` element. No need to put classes on each of the individual `td`s.

Here's a fiddle I made earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/MupLH/
which has

```html
<table>
  <col><col class="invisible"><col>
  ...
```

and the CSS:

```css
.invisible {visibility:collapse}
```

But you don't even need a class; you can also use `col:nth-child(2)` if you know the column number.

Comment: With ExtJS grid you never know actual number of column - user can drag them and change the order. And I can't see any "col" in the generated html code, so the magic is not in it. But the example you told is beautiful.